# Can you make folder with rake build?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rakefile

I have no experience with Ruby or rake or anything, but I am using [slate](https://github.com/tripit/slate) for API documentation, and it uses Ruby and rake and stuff to build the file. I know nothing at all about these things, but what I do know is this: when I do a `rake build` it updates a folder (`slate/build`). I then have to manually copy `slate/build` to `../app/docs` after every single `rake build`. Is there something I can do that will copy that folder on every `rake build` automatically for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your `Rakefile`:

```
ROOT = File.expand_path('..', __FILE__)

task :build_and_move => [:build] do
  cp_r(File.join(ROOT, 'slate/build'), File.join(ROOT, '../app/docs'))
  # or
  # mv(File.join(ROOT, 'slate/build'), File.join(ROOT, '../app/docs'))
end
```

and then run `rake build_and_move`.

Comment: Rake already includes `FileUtils` (it actually [wraps all the commands](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/v10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb#L21-L40), but they’re all there) so you don’t need the `require` and can just call e.g. `cp_r` directly.

Comment: @matt, cool, thanks for the info! I was not aware of that. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FileUtils` for this.

Docs: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-copy

Example from the docs:

> Copies src to dest. If src is a directory, this method copies all its contents recursively. If dest is a directory, copies src to dest/src.

```
FileUtils.cp 'eval.c', 'eval.c.org'
FileUtils.cp %w(cgi.rb complex.rb date.rb), '/usr/lib/ruby/1.6'
FileUtils.cp %w(cgi.rb complex.rb date.rb), '/usr/lib/ruby/1.6', :verbose => true
FileUtils.cp 'symlink', 'dest'   # copy content, "dest" is not a symlink
```